# Does the MatLab Galois Field function have an inverse?

Tags: matlab

If I have a normal matrix `A` that I convert to a GF(2) using the MatLab `gf` function to produce a GF(2) object `A_g` and then perform operations on `A_g` like FEC encoding and reshaping to produce `B_g` can I easily convert `B_g` to a normal matrix object `B` using some inverse function of `gf`

Something like this:

```
A = [0, 1, 1, 0]
A_g = gf(A)

B_g = bchenc(dataIn, 7, 4);

B = gfinv(B_g) % does gfinv exist?
% now do digital modulation on B
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to convert `B_g` to `B` by iterating over each element in the Galois array as follows:

```
    [rows, cols] = size(B_g); % get dimensions of B_g
    B = zeros(rows, cols); % declare B with same dimensions
    for row = 1:rows
        rowGF = B_g(row,:);
        for col = 1: cols
           if (rowGF(col)/1) == 1 % if the element is 1 then set to 1
               B(row, col) = 1;
           elseif (rowGF(col)/1) == 0 % if the element is 0 then set to 0
               B(row, col) = 0;
           end
        end
    end
```

Not sure if there's an inbuilt way of doing this, but this is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I came across another much simpler solution as follows:

```
B = B_g.x;
```